# Gradient symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, gradient

This maybe a silly question, but how do I type this first symbol? I can't seem to find it in any lists. Is it a small delta?

[image: mystery character]

Comment: It is just `\partial`.

Comment: `\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
$\partial J(W)$
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat that saved me some searching!

Comment: You're welcome! Sometimes a `\partial` answer can be helpful, it seems. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Schrödingers cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%C3%B6dingers-cat), the direct answer is indeed `\partial`

To add to that answer, I have found it to be very handy to have a list of latex symbols for quick lookup.

Such as: https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols

And for completness: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf